# rEFind - Installed, configured as primary boot but does not boot, only grub

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi, refind

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I install grub and rEFind. 
I was using rEFind normal, but a few days ago him stopped to work... 
I set as primary boot order, but only grub shows at bootup time.

Check this:

```
dcbasso@DanteNB:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v 
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,3000,2001,2002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,21d81aef-d1f7-4b4a-b723-989913da67f8,0x800,0x93800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(1,GPT,21d81aef-d1f7-4b4a-b723-989913da67f8,0x800,0x93800)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)  RC
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)  RC
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
dcbasso@DanteNB:~$ sudo refind-mkdefault
rEFInd is already the first entry
No changes saved.
```

After reboot the system grub back to the top bootup order and rEFind does not shows up at boot time.
As I already say, I was using in the past without problemas.
If I select to boot with reFind in UEFI boot selection EFI file, works very well!

Please help me leave reFind working back again.

Comment: Today, after leave my notebook turned off by 20 hours the rEFInd works!
I will wait a little more the close this post and I will try find a reason for that unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now it's working! I Reinstall the refind and then:

```
sudo efibootmgr -0 0001,0000,3000,2001,2002
sudo refind-install 
sudo refind-mkdefault
```

Turn off computer and waiting some time to use. Now all back to work, with my custom theme too!